# Generate Update Script MySQl Table

Tags: mysql

I have MySql table that has 250 fields, and i need to do an update, It might take hours to write the entire update manually.

In **SQL SERVER**, I have the option to "**GENERATE UPDATE SCRIPT**", I am looking for something like that option.

I tried Phpmyadmin and Navicat, but I don't find such option.

Comment: what script language you know?

Comment: The update is for a php application, do not know if that answers your question shiplu

Comment: I think someone should consider creating a different database schema that better represents your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **describe tablename** and copy the fields into excel sheet and then populate the update statement.